# Using grunt to inject your dependencies

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Here is my GruntFile

```
     files: {
                '../index.html': 
                [
                    [
                        '../node_modules/**/*.min.js',
                    ],
                    [    
                        '../js/test/test.js',
                        '../css/main.css'
                    ]
                ]
            }
```

The issue with this, is that every min.js file inside my node_modules is gonna be injected. However, I would only like to include the main file of each dependencies (which sometimes can be in node_modules//dist/ and sometimes directly at the root of dep.
Is there a way to specify, only include the "main file" of each dep ?

Let me know if it needs clarification

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are saying. If you only want to include a certain file just explicitly state it. I don't know if this was obvious but the * symbol is a catch all.

Example:

```
files: {
            '../index.html': 
            [
                [
                    '../node_modules/dist/first.min.js',
                    '../node_modules/dist/js/second.min.js' <-- usually the last one doesn't have a comma.
                ],
                [    
                    '../js/test/test.js',
                    '../css/main.css'
                ]
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Ok, but it means that every time I add a new library I have to modify my grunt file and I'd like to avoid that.